# Using STR_TO_DATE in Java to INSERT Date, with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, date, prepared-statement, string-to-datetime

Let's suppose we have a JFrame called *FrmRegistration*. Its function is inserting data into a table called *records*.

MySQL's command **desc records** would result the following:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | varchar(7)   | NO   | PRI |         |       | 
| name      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| birthday  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Within *FrmRegistration* there's a JFormattedTextField for birthday input we'll call *ftfBirthday*. In Netbeans, we put names into components by right-clicking it and going to Properties -> Code tab -> Variable name. Or right-click -> Customize code -> Rename... button.

Right-click the field and go to Properties, then in FormatterFactory, click the "..." button. Create a customized field with: ####/##/##

The reason for a JFormattedTextField is that the user wouldn't lose time by typing the slashes. They appear automatically.

What should be done in the source-code of a button in *FrmRegistration* called Insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before going to the source-code, right-click the date field and go to Properties. Copy the content of text. It should be (a = one space):

aaaa/aa/aa

It will be used in the "**} else if ("    /  /  ".equals(birthday)) {**" line.

(See the code for proper parameter)

I added some things extra, like checking if fields are empty.

```
    try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(

                                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database_name_here",
                                "username_here", "password_here")) {

                    String if = txtId.getText();
                    String name = txtName.getText();
                    String birthday = ftfBirthday.getText();

                    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(

                            "INSERT INTO records "
                            + "(id, name, birthday)"
                            + "VALUES(?,?,STR_TO_DATE(?,'%Y/%m/%d'))");

                    if (id.isEmpty()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "The ID field must be completed!");

                    } else if (name.isEmpty()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "The Name field must be completed!");

                    } else if ("    /  /  ".equals(birthday)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "The Birthday field must be completed!");

                    } else {

                        stmt.setString(1, id);
                        stmt.setString(2, name);
                        stmt.setString(3, birthday);

                        stmt.executeUpdate();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, " Data was saved successfully! ");

                    }

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "SQL command error "
                        + e.getMessage());

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                        " Database driver not found ");

        }
```

That's it. Hope it helps someone! :-)